# How to catch and re-throw all errors in MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, handler

I can't seem to find anywhere how to catch and re-throw any errors or warnings that can occur in a procedure.

What I want is the syntax to do the following:

```
create procedure myProcedure()
  begin

      declare exit handler for ANYTHING_WRONG_THAT_CAN_BE_CAUGHT_WARNINGS_INCLUDED
      begin
          rollback;
          RE_THROW THE_THING_THAT_WAS_CAUGHT;
      end;

      start transaction;
         -- do some stuff
      commit;
  end; //
```

The reason being that I want to force a rollback on an error or warning but leave it up to the client to decide what to do with the specific error.

The all-cap areas are the portions where I do not know what to put.

Thanks for any help!

Edit -------

I have since learned it is not possible to do what I have asked :'(.

Instead I have a single error for anything that goes wrong and used the following code:

```
declare exit handler for sqlwarning, sqlexception begin
    rollback;
    call error();
end;
```

(error() does not exist)

Comment: This question would provide a partial solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18858567/mysql-exception-handler-access-exception-being-handled

Comment: why 'partial'? what's missing?

Comment: Thanks for your question and answer, I have spent many hours in vain on the same topic, finally I found your post. cheers

Answer (score 30):

To catch all SQL exceptions, use:

```
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
```

`SQLWARNINGS` can be used to catch warnings also.

Inside the exception handler, to raise the error or warning that was just caught, use:

```
RESIGNAL
```

See the documentation for the RESIGNAL statement:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/resignal.html

This is available since MySQL 5.5

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. Works as expected! Thank you!