# MySQL exception handler access exception being handled

Tags: mysql, exception, signals

I'm trying to [rollback on an error, but still let the client receive the error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13095832/how-to-catch-and-re-throw-all-errors-in-mysql). This might actually be impossible, unless there is a way to access the error in an exception handler.

It's possible to "throw" from an exception, i.e. it's possible to [raise a signal](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE p ()
BEGIN
  DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
  BEGIN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE VALUE '99999'
      SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'An error occurred';
  END;
  DROP TABLE no_such_table;
END;
```

But this sample code from the MySQL doc looks *horrible*, because it literally *swallows all errors* and jams them into one.

[`SHOW ERRORS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-errors.html) seems relevant, but I don't see any way to work with it programmatically, e.g. `SELECT Code FROM (SHOW ERRORS);` is not possible.

Is this possible?  Is there a better practice that I'm missing entirely?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like [`RESIGNAL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/resignal.html) is what you are looking for.

> `RESIGNAL` makes it possible to both handle an error and return the error information. Otherwise, by executing an SQL statement within the handler, information that caused the handler's activation is destroyed. `RESIGNAL` also can make some procedures shorter if a given handler can handle part of a situation, then pass the condition “up the line” to another handler.

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `test`.`resig` $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `test`.`resig` ()
BEGIN

DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
BEGIN
  SELECT 'I executed something before throwing the error' as `this_works`;
  RESIGNAL;
END;

SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE baz = 0;

END $$

DELIMITER ;


mysql> call resig();
+------------------------------------------------+
| this_works                                     |
+------------------------------------------------+
| I executed something before throwing the error |
+------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'foo' in 'field list'

mysql>
```

Comment: Thanks. I have no idea why that wouldn't be pointed to in the SIGNAL or DECLARE HANDLER documentation.