# MySQL transaction doesn't return enough error message to help debug

Tags: mysql, error-handling, transactions

The following transaction runs no problem. However, once a transaction is failed, for example, column number doesn't match, or any other reason, it will only show an error message "'SQLWARNING: The request at Linux system time ${LINUX_SYSTEM_TIME} insert failed. Th data will be rollbacked'" but no error message to show the actual failure.  May I know if there is any MySQL way to show an error message in a MySQL transaction? Thank you.

```
       delimiter //

        CREATE PROCEDURE 123
        BEGIN

            DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLWARNING

                BEGIN

                ROLLBACK;

                SELECT 'SQLWARNING: The request at Linux system time ${LINUX_SYSTEM_TIME} insert failed. Th data will be rollbacked';

                END;


            DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION

                BEGIN

                ROLLBACK;

                SELECT 'The request at Linux system time ${LINUX_SYSTEM_TIME} insert failed. Th data will be rollbacked';

                END;

            START TRANSACTION;

            <do whatever we need in transaction>

            COMMIT;

            END //

            CALL 123;

            DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS
```

Comment: I think you are looking for [`resignal`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18858567/mysql-exception-handler-access-exception-being-handled)

Comment: @Solarflare: yes, resignal does exactly what i need. really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to highlight the answer I kindly got from @@Solarflare.  Resignal is an easy solution here ([MySQL exception handler access exception being handled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18858567/mysql-exception-handler-access-exception-being-handled)):

```
                DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLWARNING

                BEGIN

                ROLLBACK;

                SELECT 'SQLWARNING: whatever error message';

                RESIGNAL;

                END;


            DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION

                BEGIN

                ROLLBACK;

                SELECT 'SQLWARNING: whatever error message;'

                RESIGNAL;

                END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Turn on error logging.  http://www.pontikis.net/blog/how-and-when-to-enable-mysql-logs has a good tutorial.